# Initializing struct array with arrays as elements of the struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to initialize an array of structs that contain an array. Looking at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665339/struct-array-initialization-in-c) and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856045/initialize-values-of-array-in-a-struct), 
I think a pretty reasonable attempt is this:

```
struct Score_t{
    int * dice;
    int numDice;
    int value;
};
struct Score_t Scores[NUMSCORES] = {
    [0]={{0,0,0},3,1000},
    [1]={{1,1,1},3,200},
    [2]={{2,2,2},3,300},
    [3]={{3,3,3},3,400},
    [4]={{4,4,4},3,500},
    [5]={{5,5,5},3,600},
    [6]={{0},3,100},
    [7]={{4},3,50}
};
```

However I can't get this to compile. Do you have any ways to get this done?

Edit: Forgot the error message: (snipped)

```
  [5]={{5,5,5},3,600},
  ^
greed.c:79:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘Scores[5].dice’) [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘Scores[5].dice’) [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘Scores[5].dice’) [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
greed.c:79:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘Scores[5].dice’) [enabled by default]
greed.c:80:2: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: E.g change `[0]={{0,0,0},3,1000},` to `[0]={(int[]){0,0,0},3,1000},`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that was it. Do you want to submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Entries `6` and `7` seem incorrect: `numDice` is `3`, but there is only `1` die.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I learnt this new method from this post. I have one query. Do we need to manually free the allocation done as per above method?

Comment: @cm161 It is such as automatic variables
So release is not required. On the contrary, there is a need to consider the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int *` can't be initialized with `{  }` (not match)
So change to like this.

```
struct Score_t Scores[NUMSCORES] = {
    [0]={(int[]){0,0,0},3,1000},
    [1]={(int[]){1,1,1},3,200},
    [2]={(int[]){2,2,2},3,300},
    [3]={(int[]){3,3,3},3,400},
    [4]={(int[]){4,4,4},3,500},
    [5]={(int[]){5,5,5},3,600},
    [6]={(int[]){0},3,100}, //It doesn't know the number of elements
    [7]={(int[]){4},3,50}   //change to [7]={(int[3]){4},3,50} or [7]={(int[]){4},1,50}
};
```

Comment: note: if the numbers in the inner array are not going to be edited at runtime, use `const int *` in the struct and `(const int[])` in the literal

Comment: in the case, also change  `int * dice;`.